# I want to loop a bot in python

Tags: python, loops, twitter, bots, host

**the code of my bot written in python**

*can someone tell me how to loop because I want to host on https://www.evennode.com/*

```
    #import modules
    import tweepy 
    import time
    
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('','') #key
    auth.set_access_token('', '')  #token
    
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    
    user = api.me()

    search = '#Evangelion'  #code
    numeroDeTweets = 40 #code
    
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numeroDeTweets): #code
        try:
            print('') #code
            tweet.retweet() #code
            tweet.favorite() #code
            time.sleep(45) #code
        except tweepy.TweepError as e: #code
            print(e.reason) #code
        except StopIteration: #code
            break #code
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading the [Twitter Automation Rules](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation) and adjusting your code to remove the likes. You'd be better off using the streaming API and reacting to new Tweets, than looping over a search - that will avoid you getting duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, Evangelion is mentioned here, good. Really good. But jokes aside, as far as i understood you want to infinitely loop through twitter search result. If so, there are two methods which will do it but with the key difference.

### If you want to itereate through:

---

#### I. Every result possible before updating search queue

If you wan to do so, you just have to remove `numeroDeTweets` variable from the `items()` argument and let it iterate:

```py
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(): # No more limits!
    try:
        # your stuff here
    except:
        # and here
```

---

#### II. First `numeroDeTweets` results and then search again

In that case you have to put `for` cycle into the `while True` loop to make it infinite and add a `time.sleep()` to add some cooldown.

So it will look something like that:

```py
while True: # Doing it infinite amount of times
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numeroDeTweets): #There ARE limits!
        try:
            # your stuff here
        except:
            # and here
        finally:
            time.sleep(45) # Taking rest for search to update
```

---

Comment: man this was very good, very detailed, thank you!